# Are tie'd objects copied when the tuple is used as a key in a map?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, reference, tuples

Suppose we have a map

```
using namespace std;
unordered_map<tuple<string,string>,string> map;
```

If I do

```
string a("a"), b("b");
map.emplace( std::tie(a,b), "c" );
```

are `a` and `b` actually copied, or does the map only keep their references as did the tuple produced with `tie`?

Comment: Actually copied. The key in the map is `tuple<string, string>`, constructed from `tuple<string&, string&>` you passed in.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent copying with using references instead of pointers?

Comment: I suppose you could try `unordered_map<tuple<string&,string&>,string>`. No idea if that would work. Strikes me as a rather strange thing to want to do. For one thing, you'd have to somehow keep a bunch of `string` variables alive for as long as the map refers to them. Sounds like an XY problem - what problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: It relates to a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866571) I asked some time ago. Whatever I tried, the [simplest implementation](https://github.com/ivankp/propmap_cpp11/blob/c0125f043991c29fccaf2779928ad4529eea4e5a/propmap.hh) is the fastest on benchmark, so I thought that maybe the map doesn't actually copy the tuple elements.

Comment: @Igor: Please write answers in the _answer_ section....